# Is there any possibility of fitting bones?

Tags: export, bones, unreal-engine

I exported a character mesh (with skeleton) from Unreal Engine 4 using an FBX file.

[image: picture of the pasted mesh from unreal engine]

I think the bones are not in a good position. Can I do something with it? 
Later I would like to make a body and assign that to this skeleton

Comment: When you import the fbx, look at the import options, click armature and try different primary and secondary bone axes. In blender the length of the bone is it's y-axis (not sure what UE4 uses).